# how to stop download in notification bar using android downloading manager?

Tags: android, service, download-manager

i am working with a download manager in android. i used download manager class for this purpose. one button to start and another to stop it. i am also using a progress bar to show percentage downloaded. everything work fine but when i click on stop button it does not stop in notification bar. i have used dm.remove(id) method but it does not work. callin download

```
dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
     request = new Request(
            Uri.parse("url"));
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
     downloadId = dm.enqueue(request);
```

only problem is with removing or stop  it.

```
dm.remove(downloadId);
```

any idea where the problem is please!!!

Comment: dm.remove(id) should remove it. I am using it and I had not problem so far. Are you downloading 1 thing at a time?

Comment: thanks tasomaniac your comment solve my problem.

Comment: Glad to help you. I am writing it as an answer, can you accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dm.remove(id) should remove it. I am using it and I had not problem so far. Are you downloading 1 thing at a time?

Comment: dm.remove(id) works fine to remove download, just the notification remains stuck in notification bar. same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751798/cancelling-ongoing-download-does-not-remove-notification/34797980